Interpreting coefficients from proportional odds logistic regression with polr()
In Stata and R (polr) the ordinal logistic regression model is parameterized as
$$logit(P(Y \leq j)) = \beta_{j0} - \eta_1 x_1 - \cdots - \eta_p x_p$$
where $\eta_i = -\beta_i$.
The interpretation therefor is for a binary variable going from 0 to 1 as well as for a continuous variable (given $ \Delta x_1 = 1$)
$$logit(P(Y \leq j) \mid x_1 = 1) - logit(P(Y \leq j) \mid x_1 = 0) = -\eta_1$$
The interpretation of the $\eta_i$ in terms of the odds if $x_1$ goes from 0 to 1 or for continuos variables if $ \Delta x_1 = 1$ is then given by $$\frac{\frac{P(Y > j \mid x = 1)}{P(Y \leq j \mid x = 1)}}{\frac{P(Y > j \mid x = 0)}{P(Y \leq j \mid x = 0)}} = \exp(\eta) 
$$
or
$$ \frac{P(Y > j \mid x_1 = 1)}{P(Y \leq j \mid x_1 = 1)} = \frac{P(Y > j \mid x_1 = 0)}{P(Y \leq j \mid x_1 = 0)} \cdot exp(\eta_1) $$
Now I have this data:



Variable
Description
Categories / Values




sex
Self-reported gender
0: Male; 1: Female


age
Self-reported age
Continuous


bloodPressure
High blood pressure
1: Yes; 2: No; 3: Borderline hypertension


health
General health condition
1: Excellent; 2: Very good; 3: Good; 4: Fair; 5: Poor


smoking
Current smoking habits
1: Currently smokes; 2: Quit smoking; 3: Never smoked regularly


bmi_p
Body mass index
Continuous



In R we perform this
hc_dat$health <- as.ordered(hc_dat$health)
hc_dat$health <- factor(hc_dat$health, levels=rev(levels(hc_dat$health)), labels = c("1Poor","2Fair","3Good","4Very good","5Excellent"))

.
Additionaly we center the continuous variables by substractin the mean and setting refernce categories for bloodPressure = "Yes" and for smoking = "Curr"
We estimate
Call:
polr(formula = health ~ sex + age + bmi_p + smoking + bloodPressure, 
    data = hc_dat, na.action = na.exclude, Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                           Value Std. Error t value
sexfemale               -0.20574   0.023919  -8.601
age                     -0.00432   0.000765  -5.647
bmi_p                   -0.08357   0.002052 -40.727
smokingQuit              0.62178   0.054557  11.397
smokingNever             0.83112   0.050805  16.359
bloodPressureNo          0.95162   0.029744  31.994
bloodPressureBorderline  0.64228   0.046117  13.927

Intercepts:
                      Value    Std. Error t value 
1Poor|2Fair            -2.6697   0.0636   -41.9645
2Fair|3Good            -0.7340   0.0537   -13.6617
3Good|4Very good        1.0777   0.0538    20.0169
4Very good|5Excellent   2.9515   0.0564    52.3319

Residual Deviance: 63778.49 
AIC: 63800.49

With
> exp(coef(m1_polr))
  sexfemale          age        bmi_p  smokingQuit smokingNever 
  0.8579571    0.9870031    0.9067231    1.8641091    2.3980687

Now my questions:

Taking sexfemale as example we would interpret: For female the odds of being more likely (i.e., "2Fair", "3Good", "4Very good", "5Excellent" versus "1Poor") to be healthy is 0.85 times that of males, holding constant all other variables. Meaning the odds for females are 14.204292% lower. Meaning males are more likely to be healthy?

For the continuous varibales it is kind of the same. A 1 unit increase, decreases the odds of being more likely (i.e., "2Fair", "3Good", "4Very good", "5Excellent" versus "1Poor") to be healthy by 1.299687% for age and 9.327685% foor bmi_p? Intuitively, I would say it's logically valid since the older you get, the more health problems you are likely to have, and the same goes for higher body weight.

& 4. (minor questions) Why do we center the variables with their mean and why do we reverse the levels. This reversing might lead me to wrong interpretations. As well as the fact that my professor defined the model with a $+$ sign instead.


